# Does the fact that every page is reachable through www.example.com and www.example.com/index have any SEO impact?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, seo

Our website is written in .NET MVC, where every page is reachable through the URLs `www.example.com/whatever`, as well as `www.example.com/whatever/index` (since the default action for every controller is called index). Does this have any SEO impact?

Is it possible to disable URLs with explicitly typed /index (and return a 404 for those)? Is this safe?

Should there be a redirect from `www.example.com/whatever/index` to `www.example.com/whatever`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes this will have an impact on SEO. Search engines like Google do not like to see [duplicated content](https://moz.com/learn/seo/duplicate-content).

I will state this it is unlikely that the `/index` will ever be found if you do not link to it anywhere. E.G. if you always use the `www.example.com/whatever` version then the `www.example.com/whatever/index` will not be discovered.

Yes you can disable the `/index` page and it is perfectly safe to do so. *As long as you don't need to provide an `id` parameter on your routes.*

As you suggest you could do a redirect from the `/index` to `/` is one solution. To do this I would probably use something like [URL Rewrite](http://www.iis.net/learn/extensions/url-rewrite-module/creating-rewrite-rules-for-the-url-rewrite-module) in IIS. The rule would look something like this:

```
<rule name="RemoveTrailingSlashRule1" stopProcessing="true">
  <match url="(.*)/index$" />
  <conditions>
    <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
    <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
  </conditions>
  <action type="Redirect" url="{R:1}" />
</rule>
```

Myself, I would probably just use a [canonical url](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Canonical_link_element) and be done with it:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <link rel="canonical" href="http://example.com/whatever" />
  </head>
<body>
```

Comment: How would I go about disabling /index for all pages?